# How can I make an offline transaction and send it to Ethereum client network in java?

Tags: web3js, infura, android

```
 private class Myclass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //sldknfbhvsjhxcnzmcxcmj
            Web3j web3 = Web3jFactory.build(new HttpService("https://rinkeby.infura.io/...."));
            Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion =null;
            try {
                web3ClientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().sendAsync().get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String clientVersion = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();


            Log.i("checking just",clientVersion);
            Admin admin = AdminFactory.build(new HttpService("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/..."));  // defaults to http://localhost:8545/
            PersonalUnlockAccount personalUnlockAccount = null;
            try {
                personalUnlockAccount = admin.personalUnlockAccount("0x...",
                        String.valueOf(true)).send();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (personalUnlockAccount.accountUnlocked()) {
                // send a transaction
                TransactionManager transactionManager = new RawTransactionManager(
                        web3,
                        getCredentialsFromPrivateKey()
                );

                Transfer transfer = new Transfer(web3, transactionManager);

                TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = null;
                try {
                    transactionReceipt = transfer.sendFunds(
                            RECIPIENT,
                            BigDecimal.ONE,
                            Convert.Unit.ETHER,
                            GAS_PRICE,
                            GAS_LIMIT
                    ).send();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.i("checking just",clientVersion);

            return null;
        }


    }

    private Credentials getCredentialsFromWallet() throws IOException, CipherException {
        return WalletUtils.loadCredentials(
                "passphrase",
                "wallet/path"
        );
    }

    private Credentials getCredentialsFromPrivateKey() {
        return Credentials.create(PRIVATE_KEY);
    }
```